# Is there a way displaying only specific data on the table? like if the data being receive in the database contains 'SuperAdmin' dont display it?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, vuejs2

I already get all the data from the database and displayed it on my vue component. But, how can I display specific data on the table?
Like if the results from the database contains a user type of 'SuperAdmin'
I wanted to filter it like don't display if you find data related  'SuperAdmin'

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdmI8.jpg - Here is my output.

I have searched this kind of problem and nothings pops-up.

Say for example.

['Paul','paul@new.com',['Admin']

['Paul', 'paul@new.com', ['SuperAdmin']

I just want to display the first array. Since it doesn't have a user type of SuperAdmin.

```
<tr v-for="user in users.data" :key="user.id">
<td>{{user.id}}</td>
<td>{{user.name}}</td>
<td>{{user.email}}</td>
<td>{{user.type}}</td>
<td>{{user.created_at |myDate}}</td>
<td>
    <a href="#" @click="editModal(user)">
        <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
    </a>
            /
    <a href="#" @click="deleteUser(user.id)">
        <i class="fa fa-trash red"></i>
    </a>

</td>
</tr>
```

I  just displayed all the data being fetch in the database. Just wanted it to filter it somehow.

Comment: You could just filter users.data when you fetch it? Or you can make a computed property for the table in case you don't want to throw away anything.

Comment: Nice idea, still new to vue how could i just throw all data except the user.type  == 'SuperAdmin'?

Comment: Would need to see how you fetch the data. But basic filter: users.data = users.data.filter(i => i.type !== "SuperAdmin")

Comment: I fetch my data like this. 
`axios.get("api/user").then(({ data }) =>(this.users = data)); //promise function data send data to this.users = data`

Answer (score 0):

I have not used Vue in alittle while but if I remember correctly you can just use 'v-if' and it will conditionally render the data. Below is an example of how this could be done.

**Possible Solution**

```
<tr v-for="user in users.data" :key="user.id">
<div v-if="user.type == 'SuperAdmin'">
<td>{{user.id}}</td>
<td>{{user.name}}</td>
<td>{{user.email}}</td>
<td>{{user.type}}</td>
<td>{{user.created_at |myDate}}</td>
<td>
    <a href="#" @click="editModal(user)">
        <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="#" @click="deleteUser(user.id)">
        <i class="fa fa-trash red"></i>
    </a>
</td>
</div>
</tr>
```

Hope this answered your question, good luck!

Comment: This gives me a similar idea. It get's the work done but it is not the best practices. 
Btw, Thankyou.

<tr v-for="user in users.data" :key="user.id" v-if="user.type != 'SuperAdmin'">

I read the documentation

"Avoid v-if with v-for ESSENTIAL
Never use v-if on the same element as v-for."
[link](https://vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Avoid-v-if-with-v-for-essential)

Comment: That's why it is not being put on the same element as v-for, it is on a seperate div, the documentation you linked showed why you cannot use it on the same element such as <tr v-for="user in users.data" v-if="user.type == 'SuperAdmin'">. The v-if being on a separate nested div is completely fine.

Comment: I get the gist now thank you. Still, if i wrap  the td  into a div to perform v-if it will just ruin the entire table design. Any suggestions?